# PVC volume mount on Azure kubernetes takes over an hour

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have tectonic kubernetes cluster installed on Azure. It's made from tectonic-installer GH repo, from master (commit 0a7a1edb0a2eec8f3fb9e1e612a8ef1fd890c332).

```
> kubectl version                                                                       

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.2", GitCommit:"922a86cfcd65915a9b2f69f3f193b8907d741d9c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-21T08:23:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.3+coreos.0", GitCommit:"42de91f04e456f7625941a6c4aaedaa69708be1b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-07T19:44:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

On the cluster I created storage class, PVC and pod as in: https://gist.github.com/mwieczorek/28b7c779555d236a9756cb94109d6695

But the pod cannot start. When I run:

```
kubectl describe pod mypod
```

I get in events:

```
FailedMount     Unable to mount volumes for pod "mypod_default(afc68bee-88cb-11e7-a44f-000d3a28f26a)": 
timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"mypod". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[mypd]
```

In kubelet logs (https://gist.github.com/mwieczorek/900db1e10971a39942cba07e202f3c50) I see:

```
Error: Volume not attached according to node status for volume "pvc-61a8dc6a-88cb-11e7-ad19-000d3a28f2d3" 
(UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/azure-disk//subscriptions/abc/resourceGroups/tectonic-cluster-mwtest/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-61a8dc6a-88cb-11e7-ad19-000d3a28f2d3") pod "mypod" (UID: "afc68bee-88cb-11e7-a44f-000d3a28f26a")
```

When I create PVC - new disc on Azure is created. 
And after creating pod - I see on the azure portal that the disc is attached to worker VM where the pod is scheduled.

```
> fdisk -l
```

shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

I found similar issue on GH ( kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50150) but I have cluster built from master so it's not the udev rules (I checked - file /etc/udev/rules.d/66-azure-storage.rules exists)

---

Does anybody knows if it's a bug (maybe know issue)?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Also: how can I troubleshoot that further?

Comment: Ok, It occured it is mounted...after 1,5h.

Comment: 12:57:18.501127     940 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "pvc-61a8dc6a-88cb-11e7-ad19-000d3a28f2d3

Comment: 14:28:25.625797     940 operation_generator.go:670] Controller attach succeeded for volume "pvc-61a8dc6a-88cb-11e7-ad19-000d3a28f2d3

Answer (score 1):

I had test in lab, use your yaml file to create pod, after one hour, it still show pending.

```
root@k8s-master-ED3DFF55-0:~# kubectl get pod
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mypod         0/1       Pending   0          1h
task-pv-pod   1/1       Running   0          2h
```

We can use this yaml file to create pod:

**PVC**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mypvc
  namespace: kube-public
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

Output:

```
root@k8s-master-ED3DFF55-0:~# kubectl get pvc --namespace=kube-public
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mypvc     Bound     pvc-1b097337-8960-11e7-82fc-000d3a191e6a   100Gi      RWO           default        3h
```

**Pod**:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:

  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: task-pv-claim

  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
        name: task-pv-storage
```

Output:

```
root@k8s-master-ED3DFF55-0:~# kubectl get pods
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
task-pv-pod   1/1       Running   0          3h
```

As a **workaround**, we can use `default` as the **storageclass**.

In Azure, there are managed disk and unmanaged disk. if your nodes are use managed disk, two storage classes will be created to provide access to create Kubernetes persistent volumes using Azure managed disks.

They are **managed-premium** and **managed-standard** and map to `Standard_LRS` and `Premium_LRS` managed disk types respectively.

If your nodes are use non-managed disk, the default storage class will be used if persistent volume resources don't specify a storage class as part of the resource definition.

The default storage class uses non-managed blob storage and will provision the blob within an existing storage account present in the resource group or provision a new storage account.

Non-managed persistent volume types are available on all VM sizes.

More information about managed disk and non-managed disk, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes/features.md).

Here is the test result:

```
root@k8s-master-ED3DFF55-0:~# kubectl get pvc --namespace=default
NAME            STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE
shared          Pending                                                                       standard-managed   2h
shared1         Pending                                                                       managed-standard   15m
shared12        Pending                                                                       standard-managed   14m
shared123       Bound     pvc-a379ced4-897c-11e7-82fc-000d3a191e6a   2Gi        RWO           default            12m
task-pv-claim   Bound     pvc-3cefd456-8961-11e7-82fc-000d3a191e6a   3Gi        RWO           default            3h
```

---

**Update:**
Here is my K8s agent's unmanaged disk:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I understand well: you also get the problem with managed discs, and the only workaround is to use unmanaged discs? I want to use managed disc on purpose, they are also suggested solution to use for VM storage...

Comment: @mwieczorek Yes, I get the same error as you, because my k8s agent is unmanaged disk, so I can't create managed PVC, please check your k8s agent, use managed disk or unmanaged disk?

Comment: I assume by agent you mean kubelet? The k8s cluster is installed by tectonic from github master branch so it has managed discs.

Comment: @mwieczorek yes, my k8s agent is unmanaged disk, could you please check your agent via Azure portal?

Comment: What do you mean by 'check agent by portal'?

Comment: @mwieczorek I mean we can check the agent disk is managed disk or unmanaged disk via Azure portal. In Azure portal, select k8s-agent and select `disk`, in that page, we will find the disk attach to this VM, try to add a new disk, in that page, we will find this disk is managed disk or not.

Comment: Could you please try to use storage class `managed-standard`  to create PVC? does that work for you? Also does default class work for you (unmanaged disk)?

Comment: Hi, I used storageclass like in gist I wrote in main description: https://gist.github.com/mwieczorek/28b7c779555d236a9756cb94109d6695. I assume the name of storageclass is not relevant. And creating PVC is working - as I wrote. What's not working well is mounting created PV in pod - I had to wait 1,5 hour.

Comment: Looks like today it's working fine. I mean the same version of cluster, the same yaml files and the volume is mounted in seconds.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. just re-create this cluster?

Comment: I think it was not related to cluster re-create.

Comment: When I tested it before I created this question I created new cluster at least 2 times and always got that problem. And you also confirm that issue "I had test in lab, use your yaml file to create pod, after one hour, it still show pending.". So I think something changed at Azure, and now it's working..

Comment: Maybe something changed at azure:)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, "kubectl describe pod-name" does not provide suffiecient info, you need to provide k8s contoller manager logs for troubleshooting

Get the controller manager logs on master:

```
#get the "CONTAINER ID" of "/hyperkube controlle"
docker ps -a | grep "hyperkube controlle" | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'
#get controller manager logs
docker logs "CONTAINER ID" > "CONTAINER ID".log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Thanks @andyzhang. But as you can see in comments above, the issue doesn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning should be very quick. Check your controller logs to make sure the PV required by the PVC is provisioned correctly:

1. Navigate to Azure portal > cluster > Activity Log
2. Remove filter for namespaces and look for "Update Storage Account Create" entries.

In our case we needed to register our cluster subscription for the 'Microsoft.Storage' namespace so that the controller can provision the required PV. You can do this with the azure cli:

```
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.Storage
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, this command worked for me.

```
az resource update --ids /subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION-ID>/resourcegroups/<RESOURCE-GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/<AKS-CLUSTER-NAME>/agentpools/<NODE-GROUP-NAME>
```